# multiple measures and multiple dimensions

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Just a novice here but can follow directions.

I have a data frame which has certain data that is collected on people from all states of the USA, who respond to certain questions(yes/no) related to disease diagnosis. This is done over a period of 6/7 years.

My question is, I'm trying to visualize like, for each question how many people (%) responded from each state per year. I also have confidence levels for each data point(%). What is the best way to do this? any help is greatly appreciated.

A snippet of the data is added.

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AuDvlnZ8SyTBgad_YEkshyWdSgnV9A

Comment: It's generally hard to get help on SO without providing an example dataset and some code you have tried... But I think people will be happy to show you how to do this with e.g. `dplyr` if you provide an example dataset. It sounds like it would be as simple as a `group_by` and `summarize` chain. If all you care about is a plot, check out `ggplot2` and `stat_summary`.

Comment: I tried to add a snippet of data, I will try again

Comment: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AuDvlnZ8SyTBgad_YEkshyWdSgnV9A

Comment: @Schand: can you post the code you've been trying so far?

Comment: don't post your data as a link. Post it as code. [look at this thread here how to make a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)